# InvalidArgumentException: Could not find a link with a body, name, or ID attribute of [Edit]

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I am testing a page with a button that opens a modal to edit a record.

```
 $this->visit('/admin/dashboard/units')
            ->see($site->name . ' ' . '~' . ' ' . 'Units')
            ->see($unit_type->name)
            ->see($unit->unit_type_id)
            ->see($unit->status)
            ->click('Edit')
```

In my blade file I have:

```
<a class="button warning" data-open="editUnit{{ $unit->id }}">Edit</a>
```

but still did not work

but I get this error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) UnitsTest::testEditUnit InvalidArgumentException: Could not find a
>   link with a body, name, or ID attribute of [Edit].

**update**

I also tried passing an id like this

```
<a id="Edit" class="button warning" data-open="editUnit{{ $unit->id }}">Edit</a>
```

Comment: you could try to give the button an unique id and press it by it's id instead. Not sure why it doesnt find the button - it actually seems to be valid.

Comment: Most likely it does not find the object because it is not created during the test. Try to give it an id and search for it. Other way is to dump the output and search for the actual content.

Comment: I already passed an id to the a tag but still did not work

Comment: @melanholly it has created the object because the `->see($site->name)` works fine

Comment: `<a id="Edit"` the id should be unique. If you have more than one of these  the framework may fail to find it. This comes from `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php#L484

Comment: Was there any resolution or work around to this issue? I am having same problem.

Comment: @warmwhisky I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was testing the edit form on its own yet it was part of the current page, in a modal. So I combined the test with the create test like this.

```
$this->visit('/admin/dashboard/units')
            ->see($site->name . ' ' . '~' . ' ' . 'Units')
            ->seePageIs('/admin/dashboard/units')
            ->type('Unit 1', 'name')
            ->select($unit_type->id, 'unit_type_id')
            ->press('Add Unit')
            ->see('Unit saved successfully')
            ->see('Unit 1')
            ->seeInDatabase('units', [
                'name' => 'Unit 1',
                'unit_type_id' => $unit_type->id
            ])
            ->click('Edit')
            ->type('Edited Unit', 'name')
            ->select($unit_type->id, 'unit_type_id')
            ->press('Save')
            ->see('Unit Updated Successfully')
            ->see('Edited Unit')
            ->seeInDatabase('units', [
                'name' => 'Edited Unit',
                'unit_type_id' => $unit_type->id
            ])
            ->click('Delete')
            ->press('Yes')
            ->see('Unit Deleted Successfully')
            ->dontSee('Edited Unit')
            ->dontSeeInDatabase('units', [
                'name' => 'Edited Unit',
                'unit_type_id' => $unit_type->id
            ]);
```

Also it is worth noting that as from laravel 5.4 testing methods such as `visit`, `see`, `click` have been removed. See this [link](http://christoph-rumpel.com/2017/01/Browser-Tests-with-Laravel-Dusk/) and Adam has good upgrade [tutorials](https://adamwathan.me/2017/02/02/upgrading-your-test-suite-for-laravel-54/)